# Unable to import easyocr from /tmp directory AWS Lambda. ImportError: libGL.so.1

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using a AWS Lambda and storing ML model in docker container. In my model i am using easyocr library which apparently requires a writeable file system. So i am trying to store easyocr in /tmp directory. I am able to import libraries from /tmp using -
`import sys`
`sys.path.append('/tmp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/')`
While it is working fine with other libraries but with easyocr it generates the following error.

[image]

I have tried updating LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable as well but still it is not working. Any idea why?

Comment: Do you have libgl1-mesa-glx installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that library `easyocr` was found, but it can't import `libGL.so.1`.

If you can access the Docker (debian and derivatives):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx
```

If you can access the Docker (amazon-linux 2):

```
yum install mesa-libGL
```

If you only have access to your dockerfile, then add this lines:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx -y
```

Comment: I forgot to mention i am using amazon-linux 2 so apt won't work but I found solution for this I used - yum install mesa-libGL . It is working fine for me, it might help anyone else as well.

Comment: Nice, I will add it to the answer.